# Raspberry pi connection to wifi

Tags: raspbian, networking, raspbian-stretch, raspbian-jessie

I am a newbie to Raspberry Pi as I want to connect the Raspberry Pi to my Wi-Fi network which has a gateway, SSID and password.

When the Raspberry Pi is booting up it connects automatically to Wi-Fi, but when Wi-Fi is turned off manually from GUI and turn it on again it does not connect to the Internet even though it shows Wi-Fi is turned on.

After searching a lot, I come to a solution that gateway is not saved and I need to manually add a gateway every time I turn Wi-Fi on and off.

Can anyone help me with this kind of error?

Answer (score 1):

The network configuration is configured in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. Just add a line at the end of this file:

```
static routers=192.168.0.1
```

This is only an example. Of course you have to use the ip address of your gateway. This will permanently save the gateway address.

But this is only a workaround. Usually the gateway/router address is gotten from the DHCP server running on your network. Your problem indicates that something is wrong with your DHCP setup.

Comment: this statement is already present in /etc/dhcpcd.conf file but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @shan Then it seems to be a problem with the GUI network app. Look if it works from the command prompt. Execute `sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service` and look if you find the default route (gateway) with `ip route`.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, editing dhcpcd.conf file.

Comment: @shan I don't know what you have changed in `/etc/dhcpd.conf` and it suddenly worked. If my answer help you then it would be nice if you accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. Or please make your own answer and explain your solution. and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years (and annoying us ;-).